# How to include Service-Menu in Sidebar Navigation?

Tags: templates, twig, shopware, shopware6

I've tried to include the service-menu-block into the twig file of the sidebar, which is loaded in category-pages, but for some reason the this doesn't work. its the same code, thats works in the footer section. If I write some static html in there it shows, but but the pages from the menu aren't listed. could somebody help out?

This is the code from the service menu:

`{% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/layout/navigation/my-service-menu.html.twig'%}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footer navigation content, i assume thats the content you want to display inside your category page sidebar, is only loaded during the `FooterPageletLoader` and added during the `GenericPageLoader` to the `page.footer` variable for twig.

You can test that by adding `{{ dump(page.footer) }}` to the template where you wanted to include the service menu. If the dump is empty, your current page is not using the `GenericPageLoader` or does not have access to the data. If the dump is not empty, the required data for the template might need to be passed differently. For example:

```
{% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/layout/navigation/my-service-menu.html.twig'' with { 
   data: page.test
} %}
```

Shopwares GenericPageLoader can be injected if its missing from your Controller/PageLoader. In my example, MyPageStruct extends Struct and provides just one function.

```
public function __construct(
    private readonly GenericPageLoaderInterface $genericLoader
) { }

public function load(Request $request, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): MyPageStruct
{
    $page = $this->genericLoader->load($request, $salesChannelContext);
    $page = MyPageStruct::createFrom($page);
    
    $page->setDataFunction();

    return $page;
}
```

Complete examples can be found in shopwares core code: `Shopware\Storefront\Page\Account\Login\AccountLoginPageLoader`

Comment: thanks for you answer! I'll try that! could you explain how I can add the GenericPageLoader to my page?

Comment: Ive added some demo code in my answer above :)